# How do visitors get input in the timestamp?

Tags: apache2

I recently got a strange request to my website:

```
68.192.21.94 - admin [24/Nov/2020:09:51:05 -0500] "POST /doLogin HTTP/1.1" 404 4973 "-" "Abcd"
```

Somehow a malicous bot got the text "admin" to appear next to the timestamp. How is this possible? From my experience with Apache, the timestamp was provided by the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third field in Combined log format is the username given in the HTTP Basic Authentication header. If there is no HTTP authentication header in the request, the field will be `-`.

So, the bot user simply tried HTTP authentication with `admin` username and probably a password from dictionary.

You can read more information on HTTP Authentication at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)